# How can I get the "smart sharpen" effect on my images with python?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I am wondering how to **smart sharpen** an image using `python` or any  related image library like `ndimage` ,`skimage` or even `PIL`.I could find methods that actually sharpen my image but with a lot of noise and pixelating when zooming in .So since I know `Photoshop` I tried to get that smart sharpen effect which sharpens the image with a less noising and with a nice sweet contrast through python but I failed.

Notes:-
(1) methods has been tested:-

```
>>> # The 1st Method:  
>>> import Image                 
>>> import ImageFilter
>>> image.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)               
>>> Image.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE)    #Look down:1st image created  

>>> # The 2nd Method:
>>> blurred_l=scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(b,3)  
>>> filter_blurred_l = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(blurred_l, 1)  
>>> alpha =30  
>>> sharpened = blurred_l + alpha * (blurred_l - filter_blurred_l)  

>>> # The 3rd Method:  
>>> shar=imfilter(Image,'sharpen')               #Look down:2nd image created
```

(2) I found a piece of code but it's in `Perl` . I only know `Python` [In here](http://astoryworthtelling.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/smart-sharpening-in-imagemagick/)  or  [directly](http://www.columbia.edu/~jhb2147/smartsharp.pl)
(3) Here are 2 of the sharpened image using above methods the third done with *smartsharp*:
Original
[Original image http://imageshack.us/a/img600/6640/babyil.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img600/6640/babyil.jpg)
First ....................................................................second
[1st http://imageshack.us/a/img803/3897/sharp1.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img803/3897/sharp1.png)  [2nd http://imageshack.us/a/img809/2235/sharp2.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img809/2235/sharp2.png)
third MY GOAL>that's the effect I want
[3rd http://imageshack.us/a/img832/4563/smartsharp.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img832/4563/smartsharp.jpg)
(4) Here are the tool I used to create the third image above:
[smrsharpm http://imageshack.us/a/img210/2747/smartsharpentoolm.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img210/2747/smartsharpentoolm.jpg)    [smrsharp http://imageshack.us/a/img193/490/smartsharpentool.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img193/490/smartsharpentool.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it's hard to know what "Smart sharpen" does without having access to the Photoshop code.  In the meantime, you can try to mix an unsharpen mask, total variation filtering and some color adjustment (perhaps a bit of hue boost).

Also see: http://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/photoshop/sharpening.htm#

Update: here is an example of how to remove motion blur from an image:

https://github.com/stefanv/scikit-image-demos/blob/master/clock_deblur.py

(the clock image is in the same repository).  Unfortunately, scikit-image does not currently have mature deblurring / inverse filtering--but we're working on it!

Comment: But the good news is anyone knows `Perl` can modify the code I attached in my post into my lovely `Python`. By the way Thank you for scikit-image project.

Comment: Only a pleasure!  I can't access the Perl code above--would you mind checking the link?

Comment: I tried to use `Wiener-filter` from `scikit-image`but it raised an error  **Impulse response must be a callable** (i.e I don't know how to use the Impulse response parameter to do wiener -filter). I'm stuck with this spot .your previous article is wonderful but the code is in `MatLab`  and I tried to figure out what **fspecial()** function does but I failed.It seems you can help  .can you update your answer illustrating how to use the `skimage.filter.wiener()` to do smart-sharpen.Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Wiener code needs a revamp.  I've added an example above on how to motion deblur an image.  This method can also be used if you only know your blurring kernel--essentially, you apply the Fourier transform to both your image (f -> F) and your kernel (h -> H), and then return the inverse FFT of (F / H), after making sure that the amplitude is limited in places where H is close to zero. Padding avoids boundary effects, and windowing the image limits oscillations in the reconstruction.

Comment: Surely ,providing suck a method in scikit-image will push it forward as an image processing library.Through googling I noticed how people admires such an effect.Thanks,I'm going to read the code.

Comment: Agreed; we're working on it and should have it available within one or two releases.

Answer (score 4):

Photoshop's "smart sharpening" function uses a mathematical operation called *deconvolution* internally. `numpy` does have a `deconvolve()` function that could probably be pressed into service for this task, but I couldn't find a ready-made function to do smart sharpening specifically with `numpy`, so you'd probably have to code it up yourself.

An alternative approach would be to do it using the GIMP. There's a GIMP plug-in (intuitively named "G'Mic") that will do deconvolution among other sharpening algorithms, and you can automate GIMP using Python.

Comment: We have the standard Wiener-filter implemented in scikit-image, so you could generate a Gaussian kernel and apply its inverse (this process is called deconvolution).  Also see: http://yuzhikov.com/articles/BlurredImagesRestoration1.htm

There's also blind deconvolution, which tries to estimate the optimal deblur kernel, but this process can be quite sensitive.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt I reposted the links.Now I'm going to try the Wiener-filter hope it works for me as I prefer to do the task through scikit-image or may be ndimage.Thanks

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt .I read the wonderful article you provided inside the comment but the code is in `MatLab` I think.So you may want to update your answer illustrating how to use the **Wiener-filter** in the deconvolution process as it is seemed to be the correct answer.Thanks

Comment: Mr Kindal.Is there anyway to import `GIMP` as a package and may be I can use the `G'Mic` through this package as I want to make a stand alone program.If so,this would be the answer.Thanks anyway for your valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

@StefanvanderWalt
Unfortunately, the Wiener code needs a revamp. I've added an example above on how to motion deblur an image. This method can also be used if you only know your blurring kernel--essentially, you apply the Fourier transform to both your image (f -> F) and your kernel (h -> H), and then return the inverse FFT of (F / H), after making sure that the amplitude is limited in places where H is close to zero. Padding avoids boundary effects, and windowing the image limits oscillations in the reconstruction.
***What values ​​and dimensions the hann window used?***

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a rather old question and this is probably not the right answer either, but I was looking to do this with Photoshop 2020 and a python script and I had a hard time finding scattered information on how to do this so I'll post this anyway if anyone ever needs something like and this could help them.

First of all I used this python library : https://photoshop-python-api.readthedocs.io/en/0.14.0/index.html
With this API i was able to recreate basically any filter in photoshop with a python script.

Then I needed to find the string IDs for the actions to create the scripts, for this I used the Scripting Listener plugin that i found here : https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html#ScriptingListenerplugin

> I tried following the guide for Windows, but it actually didn't work
> at first, at step 4 you actually have to put the 3 folders that you
> extract from the ZIP in the "Plug-Ins" folder "Program
> Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2020\Plug-ins" just like mac-os.

Then is just a matter of executing whatever filter in photoshop and get the JS or VBS log from the listener and converting it in python.

This is an example of the JS log for the Smart Sharpen:

```
var idsmartSharpen = stringIDToTypeID( "smartSharpen" );
var desc186 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idpresetKind = stringIDToTypeID( "presetKind" );
var idpresetKindType = stringIDToTypeID( "presetKindType" );
var idpresetKindCustom = stringIDToTypeID( "presetKindCustom" );
desc186.putEnumerated( idpresetKind, idpresetKindType, idpresetKindCustom );
var iduseLegacy = stringIDToTypeID( "useLegacy" );
desc186.putBoolean( iduseLegacy, false );
var idAmnt = charIDToTypeID( "Amnt" );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc186.putUnitDouble( idAmnt, idPrc, 100.000000 );
var idRds = charIDToTypeID( "Rds " );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc186.putUnitDouble( idRds, idPxl, 1.100000 );
var idnoiseReduction = stringIDToTypeID( "noiseReduction" );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc186.putUnitDouble( idnoiseReduction, idPrc, 50.000000 );
var idblur = charIDToTypeID( "blur" );
var idblurType = stringIDToTypeID( "blurType" );
var idlensBlur = stringIDToTypeID( "lensBlur" );
desc186.putEnumerated( idblur, idblurType, idlensBlur );
executeAction( idsmartSharpen, desc186, DialogModes.NO );
```

In python I just copied the log and changed a few things like this:

```
import photoshop.api as ps

app = ps.Application()
docRef = app.activeDocument

def SmartSharpen(amount: int, radius: float, denoise: float):
    idsmartSharpen = app.stringIDToTypeID( "smartSharpen" );
    desc179 = ps.ActionDescriptor();
    idpresetKind = app.stringIDToTypeID( "presetKind" );
    idpresetKindType = app.stringIDToTypeID( "presetKindType" );
    idpresetKindCustom = app.stringIDToTypeID( "presetKindCustom" );
    desc179.putEnumerated( idpresetKind, idpresetKindType, idpresetKindCustom );
    
    iduseLegacy = app.stringIDToTypeID( "useLegacy" );
    desc179.putBoolean( iduseLegacy, False );
    
    idAmnt = app.charIDToTypeID( "Amnt" );
    idPrc = app.charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
    desc179.putUnitDouble( idAmnt, idPrc, amount );
    
    idRds = app.charIDToTypeID( "Rds " );
    idPxl = app.charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc179.putUnitDouble( idRds, idPxl, radius );
    
    idnoiseReduction = app.stringIDToTypeID( "noiseReduction" );
    idPrc = app.charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
    desc179.putUnitDouble( idnoiseReduction, idPrc, denoise );
    
    idblur = app.charIDToTypeID( "blur" );
    idblurType = app.stringIDToTypeID( "blurType" );
    idlensBlur = app.stringIDToTypeID( "lensBlur" );
    desc179.putEnumerated( idblur, idblurType, idlensBlur );
    
    app.executeAction( idsmartSharpen, desc179, 3 );

SmartSharpen(50, 1.1, 100)
```

Actually in the python library there was already an example for the Smart Sharpening but with its EventID.SmartSharpen i wasn't getting the same results for some reason. Also to change the blur type you have to know the actual stringID, which unless there's a documentation somewhere that I wasn't able to find, I was only able to get it from the logs.

---

To end this, an unrelated note to this question, for some filter that i needed like "Reduce Noise", the class "ActionList" is used but in the python library currently is not implemented yet, for now I managed by simply creating it myself by simply coping the already present "ActionDescription" and changing the name and a few methods that I needed by following the documentation here: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-vbs-ref.pdf#ActionList.
I'll just put it here in case somebody may ever need this because I had a hard time finding anything about this:

```
"""This object provides an array-style mechanism for storing dta.

"""

# Import built-in modules
from pathlib import Path

# Import local modules
from photoshop.api._core import Photoshop
from photoshop.api.action_list import ActionList
from photoshop.api.action_reference import ActionReference
from photoshop.api.enumerations import DescValueType

class ActionList(Photoshop):
    object_name = "ActionList"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def count(self):
        """The number of keys contained in the descriptor."""
        return self.app.count

    def clear(self):
        """Clears the descriptor."""
        self.app.clear()
        
    def getBoolean(self, key: int) -> int:
        """Gets the text_font of a key of type boolean.

        Args:
            key (str): key of type boolean.

        Returns:
            bool: The text_font of a key of type boolean.

        """
        return self.app.getBoolean(key)

    def getClass(self, key):
        """Gets the text_font of a key of type class.

        Args:
            key (str): The key of type class.

        Returns:
            int: The text_font of a key of type class.

        """
        return self.app.getClass(key)

    def getData(self, key: int) -> int:
        """Gets raw byte data as a string value."""
        return self.app.getData(key)

    def getDouble(self, key: int) -> int:
        """Gets the value of a key of type double."""
        return self.app.getDouble(key)

    def getEnumerationType(self, index: int) -> int:
        """Gets the enumeration type of a key."""
        return self.app.getEnumerationType(index)

    def getEnumerationValue(self, index: int) -> int:
        """Gets the enumeration value of a key."""
        return self.app.getEnumerationValue(index)

    def getInteger(self, index: int) -> int:
        """Gets the value of a key of type integer."""
        return self.app.getInteger(index)

    def getKey(self, index: int) -> int:
        """Gets the ID of the key provided by index."""
        return self.app.getKey(index)

    def getLargeInteger(self, index: int) -> int:
        """Gets the value of a key of type large integer."""
        return self.app.getLargeInteger(index)

    def getList(self, index: int) -> ActionList:
        """Gets the value of a key of type list."""
        return ActionList(self.app.getList(index))

    def getObjectType(self, key: int) -> int:
        """Gets the class ID of an object in a key of type object."""
        return self.app.getObjectType(key)

    def getObjectValue(self, key: int) -> int:
        """Get the class ID of an object in a key of type object."""
        return self.app.getObjectValue(key)

    def getPath(self, key: int) -> Path:
        """Gets the value of a key of type."""
        return Path(self.app.getPath(key))

    def getReference(self, key: int) -> ActionReference:
        """Gets the value of a key of type."""
        return ActionReference(self.app.getReference(key))

    def getString(self, key: int) -> str:
        """Gets the value of a key of type."""
        return self.app.getString(key)

    def getType(self, key: int) -> DescValueType:
        """Gets the type of a key."""
        return DescValueType(self.app.getType(key))

    def getUnitDoubleType(self, key: int) -> int:
        """Gets the unit type of a key of type UnitDouble."""
        return self.app.getUnitDoubleType(key)

    def getUnitDoubleValue(self, key: int) -> int:
        """Gets the unit type of a key of type UnitDouble."""
        return self.app.getUnitDoubleValue(key)

    def hasKey(self, key: int) -> bool:
        """Checks whether the descriptor contains the provided key."""
        return self.app.hasKey(key)

    def isEqual(self, otherDesc) -> bool:
        """Determines whether the descriptor is the same as another descriptor.

        Args:
            otherDesc (.action_descriptor.ActionDescriptor):

        """
        return self.app.isEqual(otherDesc)

    def putBoolean(self, key: int, value: bool):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is boolean."""
        self.app.putBoolean(key, value)

    def putClass(self, key: int, value: int):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is class."""
        self.app.putClass(key, value)

    def putData(self, key: int, value: str):
        """Puts raw byte data as a string value."""
        self.app.putData(key, value)

    def putDouble(self, key: int, value: int):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is double."""
        self.app.putDouble(key, value)

    def putEnumerated(self, key: int, enum_type: int, value: int):
        """Sets the enumeration type and value for a key."""
        self.app.putEnumerated(key, enum_type, value)

    def putInteger(self, key: int, value: int):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is integer."""
        self.app.putInteger(key, value)

    def putLargeInteger(self, key: int, value: int):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is large integer."""
        self.app.putLargeInteger(key, value)

    def putList(self, key: int, value: ActionList):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is an ActionList object."""
        self.app.putList(key, value)

    def putObject(self, class_id: int, value):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is an object."""
        self.app.putObject(class_id, value)

    def putPath(self, key: int, value: str):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is path."""
        self.app.putPath(key, value)

    def putReference(self, key: int, value: ActionReference):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is an object reference."""
        self.app.putReference(key, value)

    def putString(self, key: int, value: str):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is string."""
        self.app.putString(key, value)

    def putUnitDouble(self, key: int, unit_id: int, value: int):
        """Sets the value for a key whose type is a unit value formatted as
        double."""
        self.app.putUnitDouble(key, unit_id, value)

    def toStream(self) -> str:
        """Gets the entire descriptor as as stream of bytes,
        for writing to disk."""
        return self.app.toSteadm()
```